# changing from C++ code to C code

Tags: c++, c, std, stdvector

```
std::vector<MyRect> detectObjects( MyImage* _img, MySize minSize, MySize maxSize,
                                   myCascade* cascade, float scaleFactor,
                                   int minNeighbors)
```

The error says that C link function cannot return this C++ class `std::vector<_Ty>`.

How do I change the code to make it work?

Comment: If you want to give the function C linkage, make it accept an extra non-const pointer parameter instead of returning that type.

Comment: You need to get it to return an array of MyRects, or a pointer to a list of MyRects.  There are no vectors in C.

Comment: I'd suggest to stay with C++ the *whole* way. What exactly makes you want to use the C linker on that? Also, please copy'n'paste the error, don't paraphrase it.